# CSS - Gray color turns into white at printing

Tags: css

```
div {
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
}
```

The above has a nice gray color on screen but when I try to print it, it results in a white. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [color-adjust](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color-adjust) in your CSS to tell the user agent to print background colours:

```
div {
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
  background-color:#dcdcdc !important;
}
```

You might also need to enable background graphics in your printing settings in your browser. In Chrome it's

- Open your Chrome browser and go to File > Print.
- In the left-hand menu, click on More settings.
- Scroll down until you find the Background graphics checkbox.
- Click the checkbox to activate background graphics.

Comment: It still prints white on preview...

Comment: I've updated the answer. You might need to specifically add the background colour with `!important` and enable background graphics in the print settings of your browser

Comment: Thanks! In fact, only the last setting was needed for me, even without the property. I didn't think that was a matter of the browser.

Comment: Side note: `print-color-adjust: exact;` can also make sure font which was intentionally left invisible (white-on-white) doesn't have its color changed by the browser, making it visible.

Comment: I didn't need to use `!important` but this did fix the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

```
@media print {
    div{
        background-color: #dcdcdc;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 